# which library or framework can be used to render iOS UIViews?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cocoa

I'm working on a project that allows users to do ui design in browser for iphone apps. it sounds simple but after research into existing libraries/frameworks such as jquerymobile, kendoui mobile, i found none of them can produce exactly what ui could be look like on iOS devices. I think the primary reason is the underlying layout and rendering mechanisms of iOS and html are very much different. for example it's very difficult to implement the `NSString -(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size`. any advice? thanks!

Comment: Why do you think implementing UIKit in any other language/framework would be easy? If it would be easy many others would've done it the last 5 years.

Comment: good point! i think the reasons are a) there is no *real* need for an implementation in another language, everybody think it's apple's plate and tries to avoid it; b) apple does a great job to keep it unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are no libraries to my knowledge, but you can use graphics such as these to help you out:

http://graffletopia.com/images/previews/495/original.png?1253806703

Combine the images in here with jQuery and you will be able to create your own library

Comment: yes, it's an option but seems no way to deal with things like tintColor, sizeToFit. thanks